What are all the valid extensions for Get-Command -CommandType Application in Powershell 7?
I'm writing a function that launches applications via Get-Command $CommandName -CommandType Application.
Reading the documentation here says that the accepted extensions for -CommandType Application are .txt, .exe, and .dll files.
But this isn't true. I've launched .cmd, .bat, .ps1, and other file extensions using -CommandType Application
I need to know the full range of valid executable extensions for Get-Command -CommandType Application.

https://superuser.com/q/228680/53953 Not sure why you need a list of those extensions, though. Try to launch the file, and handle the error if it isn't executable. This prevents you having to maintain a list that can change over time.

The documentation isn’t an extensive list of file extensions.

The documentation is lacking on that extension list, issue #11528 was submitted to the MS Docs repo to clarify this.
-CommandType Application will read as follow once the PR is pushed to learn.microsoft.com:

Application: Searches folders in the $env:PATH environment variable for non-PowerShell executable files. On Windows, executable files have a file extension that is listed in the $env:PATHEXT environment variable.


If you want to know what the cmdlet uses behind the scenes you can inspect the source code. Get-Command behind the scenes essentially uses $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommands, if you inspect the source for CommandInvocationIntrinsics from there you can see that this class uses CommandSearcher and in there you will see they have this comment:

We are never going to look for non-executable commands in CommandSearcher.
Even though file types like .DOC, .LOG,.TXT, etc. can be opened / invoked, users think of these as files, not applications.
So I don't think we should show applications with the additional extensions at all.
Applications should only include files whose extensions are in the PATHEXT list and these would only be returned with the All parameter.

That comment gives a hint that they're using a hardcoded list of extensions, the next step is to scroll up a bit where you will find an #if !UNIX directive (Line 1346) and lastly you can see that they use CommandDiscovery.PathExtensions and there it is, thru a bit of reflection you get that list. In the end, the list is gotten by parsing Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('PATHEXT').
$commandDiscovery = [psobject].Assembly.GetType(
    'System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery',
    $false,
    $false)

$prop = $commandDiscovery.GetProperty(
    'PathExtensions',
    [System.Reflection.BindingFlags] 'NonPublic, Static')

$prop.GetValue($type, $null)

Which ends with this list:
.com
.exe
.bat
.cmd
.vbs
.vbe
.js
.jse
.wsf
.wsh
.msc
.cpl


@KJ I don't know, I do have cpl on my system. It probably varies in different OS. I'm answering OP's question here providing the source used to filter.

Is it possible to add in the .CPL pathext ?.   Under Powershell the extension .cpl is added, when doing, under a Command prompt': ECHO %PATHEXT% this extension is not there...

@SantiagoSquarzon: My comment was a comment to K-J, and to let the readers know that cmd /c echo %PATHEXT% is not producing .cpl

@Luuk ahh ok got it

To add to Santiago's helpful answer:
Fundamentally, the search scope for file names (e.g. foo.exe), file base names (e.g. foo) or file-name wildcard patterns (e.g. foo*) passed to Get-Command's (positionally implied) -Name parameter in combination with -CommandType Application is the list of directories stored in the standard $env:Path environment variable[1], in order.

When passing wildcard expressions (e.g., foo*) to Get-Command's -Name parameter, it is indeed the list of extensions stored in environment variable $env:PATHEXT that is consulted, which in PowerShell includes extension .cpl (for Control Panel views), which PowerShell itself adds.

While Windows comes with a default list of extensions in $env:PATHEXT, it is possible to modify it (as PowerShell itself does), so the specific list depends on your system's configuration.

Unfortunately, using a wildcard expression not only differs in search behavior from using literal names - see next bullet point - it in effect ignores patterns that include an extension that is not listed in $env:PATHEXT (e.g. foo*.txt).



However, in the absence of wildcard characters (*, ?, and character set/range expressions such as [abc] / [a-c]) in a -Name argument, i.e. when given a literal name to look for, the behavior is different:

If such an effectively literal name is given and it ...

does not include a filename extension (e.g, foo):

The extensions in $env:PATHEXT are looked for (first), in order.

Additionally, any extension-less files by that name are looked for too, which can cause problems when incompletely uninstalled cross-platform tools leave extension-less Unix shell scripts behind. Note that extension-less files are not searched for when using a wildcard expression.



does include a filename extension (e.g., foo.txt):

$env:PATHEXT is irrelevant in that case, and if such a file, irrespective of its extension, is found in the directories listed in $env:PATH, it is reported.

This blurring of the lines between what is an executable (as determined via $env:PATHEXT; e.g., foo.exe) and what is (by process of elimination) a document (e.g., foo.txt) is not only problematic in the context of Get-Command, it is also problematic in the context of execution:

E.g., foo.txt will "execute" - meaning: open in the default text editor - whatever file named foo.txt happens to be found first in the list of directories stored in $env:PATH, and not a foo.txt file in the current directory, given that PowerShell requires referring to current-directory files using a path, in the simplest case .\foo.txt - see GitHub issue #12632 for a discussion.








The upshot of the above are the following insidious inconsistencies:

Get-Command foo.txt -Type Application does find a file by that literal name via $env:PATH, whereas Get-Command foo*.txt -Type Application does not: Due to the latter using a wildcard expression, extensions other than the ones listed in $env:PATHEXT are ignored.

Similarly, Get-Command foo -Type Application does find extension-less files by that literal name via $env:PATH, whereas Get-Command foo* -Type Application does not: Due to the latter using a wildcard expression, extensions-less files are ignored.

These inconsistencies have been reported in GitHub issue #24567





[1] Note that Get-Command also accepts paths as -Name arguments, in which case $env:PATH isn't relevant.

I think the list you want is defined in a CommandType enum.
Alias | Function | Filter | Cmdlet | Script | ExternalScript | Application | Configuration
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/CommandInfo.cs#L23

A reputation of 1.  Now, to get a higher rep or to try to keep it at 1....

It can't go below one. That's the minimum. There are no zero or negative reps here.

The premise of the question is the use of -CommandType Application and relates to this command type only. The other command types are not relevant here.
